# Return Records Based on Condition Comparing Aggregates of Two Child Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an invoices table that has many payments and has many invoice line items. The total of an invoice record is derived through invoice line items (quantity * price).

I'm trying to create a query that will return invoices with an outstanding balance.

```
SELECT inv.id, MAX(inv.invoice_total) as "InvoiceTotal", SUM(pt.amount) AS "TotalPayments" FROM (
  SELECT 
        i.id,
        SUM( ili.price * ili.quantity ) as "invoice_total"
     FROM
        invoices i
        JOIN invoice_line_items ili
          on i.id = ili.invoice_id
  GROUP BY i.id
  ) inv
LEFT JOIN payment_transactions pt
ON pt.invoice_id = inv.id
GROUP BY inv.id
ORDER BY inv.id DESC
```

The last piece, I figured, was to add HAVING that returns only records where Total Payments is less than the Invoice Total, but it's not working.

How am I able to achieve this? Is there a simpler approach than mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT inv.id, MAX(inv.invoice_total) as InvoiceTotal, SUM(pt.amount) AS "TotalPayments"
FROM (SELECT i.id, SUM( ili.price * ili.quantity ) as invoice_total
      FROM invoices i JOIN 
           invoice_line_items ili
           ON i.id = ili.invoice_id
      GROUP BY i.id
     ) inv LEFT JOIN
     payment_transactions pt
     ON pt.invoice_id = inv.id
GROUP BY inv.id
HAVING COALESCE(SUM(pt.amount), 0) < MAX(inv.invoice_total)
ORDER BY inv.id DESC;
```

Comment: Speedy! So, considering the setup, is it normal to have to do a "MAX(inv.invoice_total)" ? It just felt wrong to me, but then again I don't do complex queries often.

Comment: @karns . . . You can also include it in the `GROUP BY`.  The `COALESCE()` is also important to get invoices with no payments.

Comment: Thanks! I may have to clarify, however. Is the subquery a good approach? I'm thinking that the need to do a "MAX" on several of the same derived values points to a stink somewhere that means my approach was wrong in the first place. Your experience may allow my confidence to grow if you say that this is a good approach to solving the problem.

Comment: @karns . . . I think your query is fine.